# Fill remaining space between two inline-blocks with another inline-block

Tags: html, space, fill, css

I have 3 divs. Each of them is an inline-block. The left one floats left. The right one floats right. The middle one floats right too. The outer divs have fixed widths. What I want to do is, that the middle div fills the whole space between the other divs. I can't specify a width, because it should work with every width of the screen. Here's the code.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
</div>

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
}
#middle {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove `float:right;` on `#middle` and put it after `#left` and `#right` in HTML markup.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/v3QC5/3/)**

HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the working answer. First it was not working. That was because my divs were inline-block. Thats obviously not necessary while floating. Removing that solved the problem.